# pandas pivot on multiple columns gives "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas

```
print a.head()
        SubjectID    form_name feature_name feature_value feature_delta
0         533  Demographic       Gender             F           0.0
1         533  Demographic          Age            65           0.0
2         533  Demographic         Race         White           0.0
```

This pivot, with `SubjectID` as the index works:

```
print a.pivot(index='SubjectID', columns='feature_name', values='feature_value').head()
feature_name Age Gender   Race
SubjectID                     
100256        53      M  White
100626        58      M  White
100806        66      M  White
```

and the same thing only with `[SubjectID]` as the index doesn't:

```
print a.pivot(index=['SubjectID'], columns='feature_name', values='feature_value').head()
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `a.pivot_table(index=['SubjectID'], columns='feature_name', values='feature_value')` should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Function [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) doesn't support multiple columns and indexes, I think it is not implemented yet.
[Issue No. 8160](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8160) and [source1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/hjv_KeeuKsA).

But my error is different:

```
a.pivot(index=['SubjectID'], columns='feature_name', values='feature_value').head()
```

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1

But:

```
print a.pivot(index='SubjectID', columns=['feature_name'], values='feature_value').head()
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: What's your pandas version? Mine's 0.16.2 np19py27_0 (using anaconda)

Comment: cool. so I think a decent workaround for multi columns is this: `a.loc[:, 'subj_time'] = a.SubjectID + "_" + a.feature_delta` and then `a.pivot(index='subj_time', columns='feature_name', values='feature_value').head())`